# Post datetime variable from form html to python

Tags: python, flask, web

I use flask !
I try to get variables from html form to run my python code !
here some line of my code .

```
   datevisu = request.form['datevisua']
   dates = np.array([x.replace(tzinfo=None) for x in eopatch.timestamp])
   date = datetime.datetime(datevisu)
   closest_date_id = np.argsort(abs(date-dates))[0]
```

I get this error !

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Any help please !

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Provide the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
datevisu = int(request.form['datevisua'])
```

But there this will show you another bug. You do not appear to be passing in all the required parameters for method `datetime.datetime`

Comment: when I try that I get 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2017-01-12'

Comment: you need to split the string by '-', then pass each array element as a parameter into the `datetime` method. of course convert them to int first.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to subtract timestamps from a datetime object.
In the date assignment line I added a call to `.timestamp()` and then converted it to an integer:

```
date = int(datetime.datetime(datevisu).timestamp())
```